How to solve Tan of 1/2*Arctan
I was trying to solve a simple integral for which I use two substitutions:
$$
t=\tan{\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)}\qquad \text{and}\qquad y=\arctan{\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)}\,.
$$
In the end I want to get back to x but I don't know how to disentangle  $t=\tan{\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)}=\tan{\left(\frac{1}{2}\arctan{\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)}\right)}$. Do you have any suggestion?
I tried to write $\tan{\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)}$ as a function of $\tan{(y)}$, but what I get is something non trivial in $-\pi<x<\pi$ like
$$
\tan{\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)} = \frac{-1+\sqrt{1+(\tan{(y))^2}}}{\tan{(y)}}\quad \text{if   } -\pi/2<x<\pi/2 
$$
and
$$
\tan{\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)} = \frac{-1-\sqrt{1+(\tan{(y))^2}}}{\tan{(y)}}\quad \text{if   } -\pi<x<-\pi/2\text{    and   } \pi/2<x<\pi
$$

What do you mean by "get back to $x$"? Do you want to express $x$ as a function in $t$?

I want to have t as a function of x, without composition of inverse functions like the one there. If I had $t=\tan{(\arctan{(x)})}$ we'd get $t=x$ but here I don't know.

That looks reasonably correct (up to sign) and agrees with  $\tan \frac{\theta}{2} = \frac{ 1 - \cos \theta } { \sin \theta} $. What is your concern?

You are almost there.
Starting with $y = \arctan(\frac xa)$, the function  $\arctan(\frac xa)$ would usually be seen as $\mathbb R \to (-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2)$, so

you want to use your $\tan\left(\dfrac{y}{2}\right) = \dfrac{-1+\sqrt{1+(\tan{(y))^2}}}{\tan{(y)}}$ result

$\tan(y)=\dfrac xa$

so $t=\tan\left(\dfrac{y}{2}\right)=\tan\left(\dfrac{\arctan(\frac xa)}{2}\right) = \dfrac{-1+\sqrt{1+(\frac xa)^2}}{\frac xa}$.


Since $\frac{\arctan(\frac xa)}{2}$ is a function $\mathbb R \to (-\frac{\pi}4,\frac{\pi}4)$, you can also note that $t \in (-1,1)$.

$t= \dfrac{-a+\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}{x}$ if $a>0$.  There is a minor issue at $x=0$, but this is removable as it clearly sensible to get $t=0$ there.
